# bifurcation diagram MATLAB runs out of memory

Tags: matlab, memory-management

I have a 3000 x 2301 matrix 'xfinfin' in MATLAB that I want to plot in the following way:

```
for i=1:2301
    ome = 0.4 + 0.001*(i-1);
    plot(ome,xfinfin(:,i),'k.');
    hold on
end
```

But this very quickly leads to MATLAB using 100% RAM and an error shows up in the MATLAB commnad line 'Out of memory'.

Basically, this algorithm plots a bifurcation diagram of omega vs x. How do I plot this without MATLAB runnning out of memory?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have access to MATLAB but even they take some time, in Octave, your codes run without error . I changed  the line plot(ome,xfinfin(:,i),'k.'); as plot(ome*ones(3000,1),xfinfin(:,i),'k.');
which makes your codes faster You can try Octave.

Comment: Thank you. That small modification made the code run in Matlab itself without error.

Comment: Do you know why this happened?

Comment: I don't know exactly but probably the line plot(ome,xfinfin(:,i),'k.') eating so much memory. You can take a look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html?s_tid=doc_12b#brh72ex-52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should try stem, its a built-in plot function, I think it is what you need.

Comment: Yup, stem works too!